# Calculus Made Easy Chapter 14 Example 12

Tags: calculus, logarithms

The example given is to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, when

\begin{equation}
y = \left(\frac{1}{a^x}\right)^{ax}
\end{equation}

The work and answer given is

\begin{equation}
\ln{y} = ax(\ln{1} - \ln{a^x}) = -ax\ln{a^x} \\
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = -axa^x\ln{a} - a\ln{a^x} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\left(\frac{1}{a^x}\right)^{ax}(xa^{x+1}\ln{a} + a\ln{a^x})
\end{equation}

My work and answer is

\begin{equation}
y = \frac{1}{a^{ax^2}} = a^{-ax^2}\\
\ln{y} = \ln{a^{-ax^2}} = -ax^2\ln{a} \\
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = -2xa\ln{a} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2xa\ln{a}}{a^{ax^2}}
\end{equation}

It's been a while since I touched any kind of math, but am I doing something that's not mathematically sound? Or is the book wrong?

Comment: Are you aware of the chain rule? If so, what do you get after applying that on the original problem?

Comment: "Calculus Made Easy"

Answer (score 3):

Your solution looks fine. I think the given answer looks wrong: they are using the product rule to calculate
$$(-ax \ln a^x)' = -ax (\ln a^x)' + (-ax)' \ln a^x, $$
which is fine.
But, taking the long way around with the chain rule, $$(\ln a^x)' = {1\over a^x}\cdot a^x \ln a = \ln a,$$ and not $a^x\ln a$, which seems to be what is given. [Then, your answer and the modified 'theirs' coincide.] BTW, it's obviously faster to write $\ln a^x = x \ln a$ before differentiating. But you know that...

Comment: There's definitely a typo in Thompson's book: the line $$ \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} \ \ = \ \  -axa^x\ln{a} \ - \ a\ln{a^x} 
$$ _should_ read $$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} \ \  = \ \  -ax \ \ln{a} \ - \  a\ln{a^x} \ \ , $$ which is $ \ -2ax \ \ln a \ \ , \ $ agreeing with OP's result.  Thompson is likely avoiding the use of certain logarithmic identities, which would not have been as familiar to the typical reader of 1910 as they are now.